# How do I create one Hive Table when I have multiple files (in the exact same folder/directory) that have the exact same columns?

Tags: hadoop, hive, external-tables

I have about 10 files in the same HDFS location.  All files have the exact same columns (about 15) and each are about 100 rows. Each file represents data I have received on over the last 10 months (data is refreshed monthly).  I would like to create one HIVE table that merges all of the data into the tables. The table should have 15 columns with about 1,000 rows of data.

I tried using code I usually use to create tables (please see below) but when I run the script below, it executes but only grabs data from one file but not the other 9.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE database.tablename (
UserID INT,
UserName String,
Department String,
State String
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION '/location/of/the/file/'
TBLPROPERTIES ("skip.header.line.count"="1");
```

I don't receive any errors but I'm only getting some of the data, not all of it.  Should I use completely different syntax? or can I edit the script above to get the results I need?

Any help is greatly appreciated! P.S. Very new to Hadoop/HIVE so I am trying to learn as I get hit with these different scenarios.  Thank you all!

Comment: Are all files in this location `/location/of/the/file/` ? Path name is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Could you once make sure all files are placed under `'/location/of/the/file/'` location.

If there are **multiple directories** inside the table pointing location`('/location/of/the/file/')`, then set these parameters in your current hive session and run the query:

```
SET hive.mapred.supports.subdirectories=TRUE;
SET mapred.input.dir.recursive=TRUE;
```

Comment: Hi Shu, Thanks for the response.I believe the answer in this case would be there aren't multiple directories. All 10 files are in the same '/location/of/the/file/'  - "file" being the folder where all 10 files reside.  Should I add the parameters you provided above?  Or what other edits should I make to the original script?